# Loading blogspot article into a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the code below to load a blogspot article dynamically into a div but I have no chance to make it work. i want to load only BlogSpot articles. other pages loaded normal

Can anyone help me out?

Here is my code:

Before close head tad:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function(){  

jQuery('#pagecontainer').load('http://thesecretrealtruth.blogspot.com/2013/07/blog-post_9623.html', function(){alert('Content Successfully Loaded.')} );


});
</script>
```

In the body tag:

```
<div id="pagecontainer" style="width:300px; height:250px;"></div>
```

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Comment: Add a PHP file to your server and use curl to get the article. Use Ajax to load your PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load contents from another domain. More information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)